# Xcode 4.3.3 and Lion 10.7.4 grinds OS to a halt

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I have relativity old Macbook Air with **1.6 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo** and **2GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM**. Recently upgraded to **Lion 10.7.4** and **Xcode 4.3.3**. Not %100 sure, but empirical evidence seems to demonstrate that when I start using Xcode my OS gets so slow it becomes unusable i.e. the refresh rate is so bad I can see keyframes of the cursor moving across the screen.

I have done the Disk Utility repair thing to no avail (not that I thought it would help anyway). Any ideas of how to cure this ailment?

---

EDIT

Just was looking at memory upgrade options. Does the below image mean i don't have any?

[image]

Comment: This probably belongs on apple.stackexchange.com, not here, as it is not a programming question. Regardless, try opening activity monitor; it'll probably show you what the problem is. My guess is you either don't have enough RAM, or it's some obscure software problem.

Comment: @fzwo I can understand why you would think this belongs on `apple.stackexchange.com`, but I think more people here would know the answer to this question, no? Only since Xcode is a developer tool.

Comment: But it is not a programming question, and this here is a programming site. It's not my place to decide, though, that is the moderators' job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Gb and 2 cores are barely sufficient to run Lion at all, much less do any reasonably intensive development work.

Comment: So was it a mistake for me to upgrade?

Comment: For Xcode development, probably yes. I had the exact same MacBookAir (I think.. that's the first one that came out in early 2008, right?) and, although Lion ran fine (I didn't have any issue with it, it didn't flicker or anything at all, just ran fine), Xcode wasn't usable at all, Xcode slowed down a snail's speed. So.. I'd recommend getting some new hardware for development